# Introducing ingress to istio mesh

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I had an Istio mesh with mtls disabled with following pods and services. I'm using kubeadm.

```
pasan@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                                       READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
default         debug-tools                                                2/2       Running     0          2h
default         employee--debug-deployment-57947cf67-gwpjq                 2/2       Running     0          2h
default         employee--employee-deployment-5f4d7c9d78-sfmtx             2/2       Running     0          2h
default         employee--gateway-deployment-bc646bd84-wnqwq               2/2       Running     0          2h
default         employee--salary-deployment-d4969d6c8-lz7n7                2/2       Running     0          2h
default         employee--sts-deployment-7bb9b44bf7-lthc8                  1/1       Running     0          2h
default         hr--debug-deployment-86575cffb6-6wrlf                      2/2       Running     0          2h
default         hr--gateway-deployment-8c488ff6-827pf                      2/2       Running     0          2h
default         hr--hr-deployment-596946948d-rzc7z                         2/2       Running     0          2h
default         hr--sts-deployment-694d7cff97-4nz29                        1/1       Running     0          2h
default         stock-options--debug-deployment-68b8fccb97-4znlc           2/2       Running     0          2h
default         stock-options--gateway-deployment-64974b5fbb-rjrwq         2/2       Running     0          2h
default         stock-options--stock-deployment-d5c9d4bc8-dqtrr            2/2       Running     0          2h
default         stock-options--sts-deployment-66c4799599-xx9d4             1/1       Running     0          2h

pasan@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get services
NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
employee--debug-service          ClusterIP   10.104.23.141    <none>        80/TCP              2h
employee--employee-service       ClusterIP   10.96.203.80     <none>        80/TCP              2h
employee--gateway-service        ClusterIP   10.97.145.188    <none>        80/TCP              2h
employee--salary-service         ClusterIP   10.110.167.162   <none>        80/TCP              2h
employee--sts-service            ClusterIP   10.100.145.102   <none>        8080/TCP,8081/TCP   2h
hr--debug-service                ClusterIP   10.103.81.158    <none>        80/TCP              2h
hr--gateway-service              ClusterIP   10.106.183.101   <none>        80/TCP              2h
hr--hr-service                   ClusterIP   10.107.136.178   <none>        80/TCP              2h
hr--sts-service                  ClusterIP   10.105.184.100   <none>        8080/TCP,8081/TCP   2h
kubernetes                       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP             2h
stock-options--debug-service     ClusterIP   10.111.51.88     <none>        80/TCP              2h
stock-options--gateway-service   ClusterIP   10.100.81.254    <none>        80/TCP              2h
stock-options--stock-service     ClusterIP   10.96.189.100    <none>        80/TCP              2h
stock-options--sts-service       ClusterIP   10.108.59.68     <none>        8080/TCP,8081/TCP   2h
```

I accessed this service using a debug pod using the following command:

```
curl -X GET http://hr--gateway-service.default:80/info -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -v
```

As the next step, I enabled mtls in the mesh. As expected the above curl command failed.

Now I want to set up an ingress controller so I can access the service mesh as I did before.

So I set up Gateway and VirtualService as below:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: hr-ingress-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "hr--gateway-service.default"
EOF


cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hr-ingress-virtual-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - hr-ingress-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /info/
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: hr--gateway-service
EOF
```

But still I'm getting the following output

```
wso2carbon@gateway-5bd88fd679-l8jn5:~$ curl -X GET http://hr--gateway-service.default:80/info -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.106.183.101...
* Connected to hr--gateway-service.default (10.106.183.101) port 80 (#0)
> GET /info HTTP/1.1
> Host: hr--gateway-service.default
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
...
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Can you please let me know if my ingress set up is correct and how I can access the service using curl after the set up.
My Ingress services are listed as below:

```
ingress-nginx   default-http-backend                    ClusterIP   10.105.46.168    <none>         80TCP                                                                                                                    3h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx                           NodePort    10.110.75.131    172.17.17.100   80:30770/TCP,443:32478/TCP
istio-ingressgateway       NodePort    10.98.243.205    <none>        80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:31775/TCP,8060:32436/TCP,853:31351/TCP,15030:32149/TCP,15031:32653/TCP   3h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Pasan to apply Istio CRDs (VirtualServices) to incoming traffic you need to use Istio's Ingress Gateway as a point of ingress as seen here: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/

The ingressgateway is a wrapper around the envoy which is configurable using Istio's CRDs.

Basically, you don't need a second ingress controller and during istio installation, the default one is installed, find out by executing:

```
kubectl get services -n istio-system -l app=istio-ingressgateway
```

and with the Ingress Gateway ip execute:

```
curl -X GET http://{INGRESSGATEWAY_IP}/info -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H "Host: hr--gateway-service.default"
```

I added the host as a header as it is defined in the Gateway meaning that only for this host ingress is allowed.

Comment: Hi @rinormaloku I've updated my question with istio-ingressgateway's details. Can you please suggest how I can access the service now?

Comment: @PasanW. If you have a public node ip then: curl http://<public-node-ip>:<node-port>; Otherwise update the Ingress Gateway SVC to give you an External IP, by changing it's type to LoadBalancer.

Comment: @PasanW. expanded the answer with additional details about the host. 
This could make it fail too `/info/` is used in the VirtualService while in curl `/info`

Comment: Hi @rinormaloku As I have updated in the answer my ingress gateway does not have an external IP. Can you please guide me how to set it. (I'm using kubeadm on an ubuntu VirtualBox)

Comment: @PasanW. execute `kubectl edit svc {name of ingressgateway} -n istio-system` and under spec change to `type: LoadBalancer`

Comment: I think kubeadm doesn't have a definition for how to provision a loadbalancer. and that's why you actually need to stick with node port, doesn't this work `curl -X GET http://10.98.243.205/info -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H "Host: hr--gateway-service.default"`?

Comment: This works with NodePort : curl -X GET http://10.0.2.15:31380/info/ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -v

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186161/discussion-between-rinormaloku-and-pasan-w).